# In django, values(*field) doesn't give all values of ForeignKey field with sliced queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
self.model.objects.filter(pk=2)[:1].values('name', 'entry__headline')
self.model.objects.filter(pk=2).values('name', 'entry__headline')
```

Why can't the first one return all values of Foreign key field, but the second one works as expectation?

First returns:

```
QuerySet [{'name': 'My blog', 'entry__headline': 'An entry'}]
```

Second returns:

```
QuerySet [{'name': 'My blog', 'entry__headline': 'An entry'},
     {'name': 'My blog', 'entry__headline': 'Another entry'}, ...]
```

So it's like the first one can't return all results of foreign key field.

Comment: What does each one return?

Comment: ettanany, thanks a lot for your nice edits!XD

Comment: You can always use `{}` above your question text to format the code parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how list slicing works, `[:1]` means `[0:1]` (from index 0 to index 1) with `1` is not included:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3]
>>> my_list[:1]
[1]
>>> my_list[0:1]
[1]
```

`SomeModel.objects.filter(pk__gte=2)[:1]` means you're slicing a `QuerySet` and the result is list of model instances.

`SomeModel.objects.filter(pk__gte=2).values('name')[:1]` means you're slicing a `ValuesQuerySet` and the result is list of dictionaries.

Look at the following examples:

```
>>> from polls.models import Question
>>> 
>>> Question.objects.all()
[<Question: q1>, <Question: q2>, <Question: q3>]
>>> Question.objects.filter(pk__gte=2)  # returns QuerySet
[<Question: q2>, <Question: q3>]
>>> Question.objects.filter(pk__gte=2)[:1]  # slicing a QuerySet
[<Question: q2>]  # list of Question instances
>>> 
>>> Question.objects.filter(pk__gte=2).values('question_text')  # returns ValuesQuerySet
[{'question_text': u'q2'}, {'question_text': u'q3'}]
>>> Question.objects.filter(pk__gte=2).values('question_text')[:1]  # slicing a ValuesQuerySet
[{'question_text': u'q2'}]  # list of dictionaries
```

**Note:** `SomeModel.objects.filter(pk=2)` would always return a `QuerySet` that contains 1 object (with pk=2 in this case).

Comment: Oh, you mean it's the returned results get sliced but not the queryset?

Comment: Thanks, I tried, you're right! But I expected [:1] would take the first model object but not the first result returned by values(), if so, I expect it should be like self.model.objects.filter(pk=2).values(*fields)[:1].

Comment: Yes, the returned result is sliced.

Comment: I tried an noticed both model.objects.filter(pk=2).values(*fields)[:1] and model.objects.filter(pk=2)[:1].values(*fields) do the same job, is this a bug of django? Because I actually wanna slice the objects instead of the results returned by values().

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve exactly. Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Comment: Actually I wanna apply the slice on the model objects like model.objects.filter(pk__gte=3).[:2] to get the first two objects rather than get slice applied on the returned results.

Comment: `model.objects.filter(pk__gte=3)[:2] ` means you're slicing the result of `model.objects.filter(pk__gte=3)` to take only the first 2 objects

Comment: Yes, it works like what you said without .values(), but as you can see from above, If I try model.objects.filter(pk__gte=2)[:2].values('name', 'entry__headline'), it will get the results sliced instead the model objects.

Answer (score 1):

Edge,

pk(primary key) is always unique. It is one of the purposes of a primary key. This in turn will help indexing. So, I am not sure why is the second returning multiple objects in the query set.

PS: please correct me if I am wrong.